# Oracle table level trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the Date and time when QTY for Item A and Loc UK gets updated.
Can I have where clause in trigger??

```
CREATE TABLE tr_test (
item VARCHAR2 (10),
loc VARCHAR2 (10),
WHEN DATE,
qty );

insert into TR_TEST values ('A','UK',to_date('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY',100);
insert into TR_TEST values ('B','US',to_date('01/01/2013','MM/DD/YYYY',200);

 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TEST_TRIGGER"
   BEFORE UPDATE
   ON tr_test
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF UPDATING ('QTY')
   THEN

      INSERT INTO tr_test_1
                  (item, loc, WHEN, qty)
         SELECT :OLD.item, :OLD.loc, SYSDATE, :OLD.qty
           FROM DUAL;

      INSERT INTO tr_test_1
                  (item`enter code here`, loc, WHEN, oh)
         SELECT :OLD.item, :OLD.loc, SYSDATE, :NEW.qty
           FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I see what the question is.  Your title talks about a table-level trigger, you've posted a row-level trigger. You've posted `insert` statements but then a `before update` trigger. You ask about a "where clause in a trigger" but you don't tell us what that would do. I don't see an answerable question here.

Comment: Plus there is no such thing as a "table level trigger". It's either a "row level trigger" or a "statement level trigger"

Comment: Thank you for the respond guys..Sorry my question was not very clear.I am looking for a row level trigger which will insert Item,loc,old qty,new qty and updated time for this one record when qty gets updated.

Comment: Mean time I wrote a pearl script which will capture the QTY, sysdate every 5min. One of our Job is changing the QTY in Batch process.I want to find what time the change is happening so I can find the Job which is doing it.                                                  #!/usr/bin/perl
while(1)
{
 system "runSQLScript.ksh ./300.sql";
  sleep 300;
}